# Do I actually need any of these default schemas?

Tags: sql-server, schema

When creating a new database there are about a dozen default schemas that are added. A few of them are fairly important (dbo, sys, and INFORMATION_SCHEMA in particular).

Some of the others I understand the purpose for, such as guest, for example.

But why is there a schema for every role by default? Especially, for example, db_denydatareader and db_denydatawriter. Does anyone actually put anything in those schemas or is their only purpose in life to take up screen real estate when I'm browsing in SSMS?

Assuming I already know that I will never put anything in any of the following schemas, is there any reason not to remove them?

- db_accessadmin
- db_backupoperator
- db_datareader
- db_datawriter
- db_ddladmin
- db_denydatareader
- db_denydatawriter
- db_owner
- db_securityadmin
- guest

Note that I am NOT talking about removing any of these roles... just the schemas.

Comment: Why? Are those schemas somehow bothering you? I don't see how you would stand to gain anything at all here other than maybe 10kb total storage on the server.

Comment: Yes, they are bothering me. They take up screen real estate as I mentioned. I would rather look at a list of less than 30 schemas we actually use and fit in one screen than of 40+ that goes off the screen.

Comment: I'm also asking to learn whether they do serve any purpose. For example, had I listed "sys" in the list above someone would inform me of how important the sys schema is. Likewise, I'd like to know if any of the rest of these have any value that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Screen real estate? You should just query schemas when you need to see them. select * from sys.schemas (you could even exclude the ones you don't want to see with a where clause). I have never bothered to worry about those schemas to be honest. I would maybe try it out on a test database and see what happens....think I will do the same just so I know. Here is an interesting reply from Hugo Kornelius on this. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/db_owner-is-a-schema/#post-1854611

Comment: @SeanLange Yep, that's exactly what I'm doing (trying on dev db). Thanks for the link, that's interesting.